# Getting and randomizing questions from JSON file doesn't produce expected output

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, ionic-framework

I have followed a tutorial on the internet [for my Quiz.](https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-data-driven-quiz-app-in-ionic-2-part-2/)

I wanted to randomize the questions and only get 10 from my questions.json file. What am I doing wrong?

```
    ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
    this.dataService.load().then((data) => {
      data.map((question) => {
       //Added this for the questions to be randomized
        let questionOrder = question.questionText;
        question.questionText = this.randomizeQuestions(questionOrder);

        let originalOrder = question.answers;
        question.answers = this.randomizeAnswers(originalOrder);
        return question;
      });
      this.questions = data;
    });
  }

  nextSlide() {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
    this.slides.slideNext();
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }

  selectAnswer(answer, question) {
    this.hasAnswered = true;
    answer.selected = true;
    question.flashCardFlipped = true;

    if (answer.correct) {
      this.score++;
      this.passingscore = + this.score;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.hasAnswered = false;
      this.nextSlide();
      answer.selected = false;
      question.flashCardFlipped = false;
    }, 1000);
  }

 //Added this for my questions to be randomize which I tried to imitate the randomization of the answers
  randomizeQuestions(rawQuestions: any[]): any[] {
    for(let i = rawQuestions.length-1; i<10;  i++){
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      let temp = rawQuestions[i];
      rawQuestions[i] = rawQuestions[j];
      rawQuestions[j] = temp;
    }
    return rawQuestions;
  }

  randomizeAnswers(rawAnswers: any[]): any[] {
    for (let i = rawAnswers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      let temp = rawAnswers[i];
      rawAnswers[i] = rawAnswers[j];
      rawAnswers[j] = temp;
    }
    return rawAnswers;
  }
```

An example of the JSON I used which I followed from the tutorial:

```
{
"questions": [
    {
        "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/images/animals.png'/>",
        "flashCardBack": "",
        "flashCardFlipped": false,
        "questionText": "These breathe, feed, grow, and leave offspring.",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "Non-living Things", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Living Things", "correct": true, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "None of the above", "correct": false, "selected": false}
        ]
    },
     {
        "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/images/universe.png' />",
        "flashCardBack": "",
        "flashCardFlipped": false,
        "questionText": "It is the only world that supports life.",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "Mars", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Universe", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Earth", "correct": true, "selected": false}
        ]
    },
    {
        "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/images/earth.png' />",
        "flashCardBack": "",
        "flashCardFlipped": false,
        "questionText": "It was a water world with small areas of dry land",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "Old Earth", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Young Earth", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Earth", "correct": true, "selected": false}
        ]
    },
    {
        "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/images/earth.png' />",
        "flashCardBack": "",
        "flashCardFlipped": false,
        "questionText": "According to studies of ancient rocks, life began on Earth about how many years ago?",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "5 million years", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "3300 million years", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "3800 million years", "correct": true, "selected": false}
        ]
    },
    {
        "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/images/animals.png' />",
        "flashCardBack": "",
        "flashCardFlipped": false,
        "questionText": "They range from the simplest single-celled bacteria to plants, animals, and humans.",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "Living things", "correct": true, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Non-living things", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Cells", "correct": false, "selected": false}
        ]
    },
    {
        "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/images/earth.png' />",
        "flashCardBack": "",
        "flashCardFlipped": false,
        "questionText": "Comets and meteors rained down on what planet?",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "Earth", "correct": true, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Jupiter", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Venus", "correct": false, "selected": false}
        ]
    },
    {
        "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/images/earth.png' />",
        "flashCardBack": "",
        "flashCardFlipped": false,
        "questionText": "Many scientists believe that life began here.",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "Lakes and oceans", "correct": true, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Planet Earth", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Rivers and mountains", "correct": false, "selected": false}
        ]
    },
    {
        "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/images/earth.png' />",
        "flashCardBack": "",
        "flashCardFlipped": false,
        "questionText": "These are energy that came from hot springs on the seabed.",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "Black Matter", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Black Smokers", "correct": true, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "Molecular Deposit", "correct": false, "selected": false}
        ]
    },
    {
        "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/images/earth.png' />",
        "flashCardBack": "",
        "flashCardFlipped": false,
        "questionText": "It is the theory of the beginning of the universe.",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "The Big Boom Theory", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "The Big Bang Theory", "correct": true, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "The Beginning Theory", "correct": false, "selected": false}
        ]
    }
    ,
    {
        "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/images/earth.png' />",
        "flashCardBack": "",
        "flashCardFlipped": false,
        "questionText": "Astronomers believe that the universe began how many years ago?",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "16 billion years", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "14 million years", "correct": false, "selected": false},
            {"answer": "14 billion years", "correct": true, "selected": false}
        ]
    }
]
```

}

What if I have a set of 50 questions on my JSON. I want to get only ten from the JSON file and randomize those questions with the randomize answers. Any advice will do. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you rewrite this question.  You haven't described where you are having trouble.  Please see this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a generic shuffle function, not two versions of it. You can take the slice of 10 after shuffling.

Note that the questions need to be shuffled outside of the loop over the questions, while the responses should be shuffled inside such a loop.

Here is suggested code:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
    this.dataService.load().then((data) => {
        // shuffle the questions first
        this.shuffle(data);
        // Retain only the first 10
        if (data.length > 10) data.length = 10;
        // shuffle the answers per question
        data.forEach(question => shuffle(question.answers));
        this.questions = data;
    });
}

// Use a generic shuffle function. It shuffles in-place, no return needed
shuffle(arr: any[]) {
    for (let i = arr.length-1; i > 0; i++) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        [arr[j], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[j]];
    }
}
```

Comment: the shuffle is not defined why is that?

Comment: `shuffle` is defined in my answer. Of course, the above code should be part of your class, just like your original code is supposed to be.

Comment: I tried it out and it says for this part that  `shuffle(arr: any[]): any[] ` that "It is a function whose declared type is neither void nor any must return a value' 

Also, when I remove the `: any[]` then ionic serve, it crashes no error on my console.

Comment: Indeed, the function should not return a value, so the final `: any[]` should not be there. I removed it. What does "crash" mean? Your browser closes? Can you provide a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I tried running it on my mobile device and the application starts to crash. I think it has something to do with the code I inserted. I'll try to put in on fiddle.